# On jsf submit, selectOneMenu validator runs only when required="true" is setted. Why?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-1.2

I discovered that jsf validator binded to selectOneMenu, on submit is called  only when selectOneMenu have required="true". How can i resolve this to call validator without that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

> *I discovered that jsf validator binded to selectOneMenu, on submit is called only when selectOneMenu have required="true".*

That's indeed by specification. This applies to all other input elements as well, by the way.

---

> *How can i resolve this to call validator without that attribute?*

You cannot. Just specify the `required="true"` attribute if you require the enduser to select an item. It's by default optional because there may be circumstances where you don't require the enduser to select an item.

Comment: So how can i do field required validation only in validator, because in my case i need do request to server on empty selectMenu value, but i cant do that when attribute required="true" is setted.

Comment: So an empty value is allowed? Then I don't understand your problem/concern at all. What's the concrete functional requirement? What kind of validation would you like to perform?

Comment: Dropdown with empty value, on empty value selected other element must hide. So i added a4j:support onchange to update dropdown value on back bean and rerender dynamic element. Dynamic element visible by  rendered="condition". Problem is when i set dropDown to required  and its not updating bean value on empty value selected.

Comment: I do not understand the concrete problem. Perhaps you overcomplicated the approach of setting the `rendered` attribute. You can just set it to `rendered="#{not empty bean.selectedValue}"` and let `a4j:support` re-render that component. In the future, try to ask about the real concrete problem instead of asking a rather rhetorical question.